# Does matrix multiplication work inside of tensors?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products

I have the matrix M
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
a&-b&0&0 \\
b&a&0&0 \\
0&0&a&b \\
0&0&-b&a
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which I would like to split into the tensor product of two 2x2 matrices. So far, I have constructed 
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}a & -b \\
b&a\end{bmatrix}\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}
$$

My main concern is the matrix I have placed inside the other matrix. I believe this itself is valid, but not so much the operation of tensoring the two together in order to receive M. I ask, is this math valid, and if not, are there any other approaches I could take in order to create a tensor product resulting in M?

**Edit:**

This is the generalized version of a problem I am working on involving quantum circuits, and the tensor operator is used to combine the gates (2x2 matrices), so I must use it here. Essentially, I am trying to work backwards

Comment: Not really valid / usual.

Comment: It's not evidence that the product you've described is multi-linear. It's also unclear what benefits you expect to achieve from representing it as a tensor product. I would split it into the form $aI + bJ$ instead of using tensors. The properties of the matrix $I$ and $J$ are very simple with $I$ being the identity and $J^2=-I$, analogous to the complex numbers.

Comment: What does $[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}]$ have anything to do with $M$?

Comment: @runway44 it rotates the matrix so that the negative is in the lower left position when multiplied

Comment: @CyclotomicField I updated my answer as to why I need to represent it as a tensor product, but I am also interested in your representation. What method would I use to split the matrix as you have shown?

Comment: @DJNeko Just matrix addition and scalar multiplication. It's a simple decomposition and very useful to remember because for the two by two case it's essentially a matrix definition of the complex numbers with $a$ being the real part and the $b$ being the imaginary part.